# How to achieve CSS transitions with delay timers but without any easing function?

Tags: css-transitions

I want to have my styling transition after a timer, but transition without any easing. So for example, change background color from white to purple immediately after the timer.

```css
.text {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #9e9e9e;
    color: #333;
    background: #f1f2f2;
    margin: 7px;
    padding: 7px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.text:hover {
    background: #651964;
    color: white;
}
.trans1 {    
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s, background 0.4s;
    -o-transition: color 0.4s, background 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s, background 0.4s;
    transition: color 0.4s, background 0.4s;
}
.trans2 {
    -moz-transition-property: background;
    -o-transition-property: background;
    -webkit-transition-property: background;
    transition-property: background;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<span class="text trans1">Text Text</span><span class="text trans2">Text Text</span>
```

In the example you can see how `.trans2` goes from white to purple instantly after the timer completes, instead of easing in over the duration of the timer.

I know how to get this effect for a single property by using `transition-property` and `transition-delay`, but because I need multiple properties to transition at the same time, I need to use the shorthand and comma separate them.

Is there a function for this? It seems to be default when only setting the property and delay, but I tried `background 0.4s initial`, and it ignored the timer completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shorthand supports both delay and duration. You can use something like this:

```
transition: all 0 linear 0.4s;
```

Or:

```
transition: background 0 linear 0.4s, color 0 linear 0.4s;
```

These will transition instantly after a 0.4 second delay.